# Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied in SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm getting this error when accessing a stored procedure in SQL Server:

> Procedure or function 'resetdata' expects parameter '@FirstName', which was not supplied.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Client
(
    ClientID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    StreetAddress VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    Suburb VARCHAR(15)NULL,
    C_State VARCHAR(3) NULL, --CHECK (C_State IN ('QLD', 'NSW', 'VIC', 'TAS', 'SA', 'WA', 'NT', 'ACT')), 
    PostCode SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(11) NULL, 
);
GO

ALTER TABLE Client
ADD CONSTRAINT state_ CHECK (C_State IN ('QLD', 'NSW', 'VIC', 'TAS', 'SA', 'WA', 'NT', 'ACT')),
    CONSTRAINT check_post_code CHECK ([PostCode] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' or [PostCode] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]');
GO
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[resetdata]
    @FirstName varchar(50),
    @LastName varchar(50),
    @PostCode smallint
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO A1.dbo.Client (FirstName, LastName, PostCode)
    VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @PostCode)
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.resetdata;
INSERT INTO Client(FirstName, LastName, PostCode) 
VALUES ('F', 'L', 12345);
```

Comment: I'm curious as to the purpose of the procedure "dbo.resetdata". It does not reset anything; it just adds a new row. After calling the procedure, you insert a row manually, which suggests you were expecting it to do something else. Perhaps you could elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Error message means exactly what it says: your SP is expecting three arguments as declared.

This is your SP header definition:

```
create procedure [dbo].[resetdata]
    @FirstName varchar(50),
    @LastName varchar(50),
    @PostCode smallint
```

Three arguments. None of them has default.

This is how you're attempting to execute it:

```
EXEC dbo.resetdata;
```

No arguments provided. This causes the error from your question. Pass arguments to avoid error message.

Couple of things:

- if you will try to apply script of your SP to test database or another copy of your database, you will have to modify your first line with `USE A1`. I'd suggest to remove this line. Choose DB once you connect, then just run all scripts on *current* database
- `Insert INTO A1.dbo.Client` - same note about different databases and one more - if you already defined database with `USE A1` at the beginning of the script, why are you referring same DB explicitly? If your SP and table are supposed to be in same DB - don't specify DB.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. The EXEC procedure is not passing the parameters required.
2. There is a constraint on the Postcode that will fail with 12345.

The correct code to run your stored procedure would be:

```
   EXEC [dbo].[resetdata]
        @FirstName = 'F',
        @LastName = 'L',
        @PostCode = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
USE A1;
GO
create procedure [dbo].[resetdata]
@FirstName varchar(50),
@LastName varchar(50),
@PostCode smallint
AS
BEGIN
Insert INTO A1.dbo.Client (FirstName,LastName,PostCode)
VALUES(@FirstName,@LastName,@PostCode)
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.resetdata @FirstName='F', @LastName='L', @PostCode=12345
--INSERT INTO Client(FirstName,LastName,PostCode) VALUES ('F','L',12345); No need to this Insert
```

**Note:** In sample data, you are going to insert `12345` to `PostCode` column, So it seems that 5 digit numbers are valid, but you have check constraint that shows `PostCode` should be 3 or 4 digit length. If 5 digit is valid so pay attention to the `PostCode` column's data type as it's maximum value is [32767](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx). So if you want to insert a record with `PostCode` greater than this value you will get an error. May be it would be better to define it as `INT` and control it's value via a [Check Constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190377.aspx) and also change the current check constraint definition on this column.